# Check for string in sheet and put value in the last coulmn in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

How can I check the whole sheet for the string "False" and put "1" in the last column of that row in which the string appears?

I have tried this:

```
For j = 13 To lCol
    For i = 5 To RowCount
        If Sheet9.Cells(i, j).Value = "False" Then
            Sheet9.Cells(i, lCol + 1).Value = 1
        Else
            Sheet9.Cells(i, lCol + 1).Value = 0
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

but it just crashes my Excel. Help.

Comment: What happens when it crashes? What error do you receive and where?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I don't get an error, it just stays on "Not responding" and then asks to shut down or restart.

Comment: Then you might want to [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51931222/edit) the rest of your code

Comment: what are the values of `lCol` and `RowCount`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2- did you link that "show us" to the edit page? That's pretty cool.

Comment: Well "Not responding" probably means your code is still running and just takes a lot of time because you run through a lot of cells.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 there is around 800-900 lines of the code so I don't know if that would be possible

Comment: @Davesexcel  lCol = Sheet9.Cells(4, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column  RowCount = Sheet9.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlDown).Row

Comment: Are you sure that this is the section of code that's actually causing the unresponsive behavior?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 yes, because without it everything works. I'll try to just let it stay in "Not responding" and see..

Comment: So what are the values? is it 10 rows and 10 columns or 1000 rows and 1000 columns?

Comment: BTW: You are also overwriting the 1 if there is no 'false' in the last column of a row.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple formula like

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:H1,FALSE)>0,1,0)
```

to test e.g. if column A to H contain a `FALSE` and then write `1` into that cell. Just adjust columns in `A1:H1` to your needs and copy the formula down.